# I don't know why my program is giving me curly brace errors. How can I fix this ? Please help

Tags: java

I have done all of the coding from 1 week which includes a TestEmployee class where I have to check for integer range, length of string and if its a number or not. I did everything and I can't find any problem with the methods I have used....But it is giving me error at last two curly braces at the lastline of the program(SAYING WHILE LOOP EXPECTED/REACHED END OF FILE PARSING)...Please help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;

public class TestEmployeePayRoll {


    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
    String EmployeeID, FullName, result;
    double oursWorked;
    int counter = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        do{


    System.out.println("Enter the Employee ID number: "+ " ");
    EmployeeID = input.nextLine();

    if(EmployeeID.trim().length()>5)

        {

            System.out.println(" EmployeeID number must be exactly 5: " + " ");

        }
    }

     while(EmployeeID.length() > 5);

    System.out.println("Enter the First Name: ");
    String FirstName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Last Name: "+ " ");
    String LastName = input.nextLine();

    do
    {

    System.out.println("Enter the Pay Category: "+ " ");

    double PayCategory = input.nextDouble();

    Double pay = new Double(PayCategory);

    if(pay.isNaN())
    {
        System.out.println("****Enter a valid Pay Category***");
    }
        if(!(PayCategory >0 && PayCategory <5))
        {
        System.out.println("Pay Category must be between 1 and 4");
        }

        while(PayCategory < 1 || PayCategory > 4);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of hours worked: ");
            double HoursWorked = input.nextDouble();

            Double hours = new Double(HoursWorked);
            if(hours.isNaN())
        {
            System.out.println("---Enter a valid hours value---");
        }

        if(!(HoursWorked >1 && HoursWorked <80))
         {
            System.out.println("---Enter value between 1 and 80---");
         }

        while(HoursWorked < 1 || HoursWorked > 80);

        EmployeePayRoll obj1 = new EmployeePayRoll(FirstName, LastName, EmployeeID, HoursWorked, PayCategory);

        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("\n The pay details for:" + obj1.getName() + "\t\t\t" + "ID:" + EmployeeID);

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Pay Category: \t\t\t" + obj1.getPayCategory());
        System.out.println("Hours Worked: \t\t\t" + obj1.getHoursWorked());
        System.out.println("Pay Rate: \t\t\t" + obj1.getPayRate());
        System.out.println("Gross Pay:  \t\t\t" + "$"+fmt.format(obj1.getGrossPay()));
        System.out.println("Tax Payable:  \t\t\t" + "$"+fmt.format(obj1.getTaxPayable()));
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t---------");
        System.out.println("Net Pay: \t\t\t" + "$" + fmt.format(obj1.getNetPay()));
        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\n +Process another employee? (Y/N)");
        result = input.next();

        }
                     while (result.equals("Y")||result.equals("y"));

    }} //this two curly giving me errors saying 
         //reached end of file parsing/while expected...
         //It doesn't work if I add or delete curly braces..
```

Thanks

Comment: It would probably help you in general to indent your code properly.  Indent one level after each opening brace until the corresponding close brace.  If you do that consistently, it will help you see where your errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that line 57 is missing a closing brace directly before it.

`while (PayCategory < 1 || PayCategory > 4)`

After fixing this, you'll have to worry about the scoping of PayCategory.

Might I also recommend a friendly IDE with reformat capabilities?  IntelliJ does a great job at this (as does Eclipse and others).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line:

```
 while(HoursWorked < 1 || HoursWorked > 80);
```

should be:

```
 while(HoursWorked < 1 || HoursWorked > 80){
```

In other words, the while loop needs an open bracket "{" at the start and a closing bracket "}" at the end.

Comment: and while(PayCategory < 1 || PayCategory > 4);

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving you the hint you need. "Reached end of file" means that as javac was looking for the end of your while loop, it hit the end of the file before it found it. In this case, the problem is on the while loop line it's self, and it's a common bug for people to run into.

If you format your code so that each block is indented, it makes it much easier to see mistakes like this. For example:

```
public int myFunction()
    {

    if (thing)
        {
            ...blah...
            ...blah...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while
            ...blah...
            ...blah...
        }
    }
}
```

This way, it's easier to see that things don't line up to catch the error. Different people have different styles on where the place the braces, but always indenting each block of code another level makes this kind of thing easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

The do loops ending in the following two while statements appear to not have closing braces...

```
while(PayCategory < 1 || PayCategory > 4);
while(HoursWorked < 1 || HoursWorked > 80);
```